Is this an MOT failure
Just had my car MOT at BMW and they failed it on this small cut in the rear tyre.
I'm not sure if:

they are pulling a fast one
it’s safe to drive

They want £900 to change both back tyres as it’s a X-drive and are run flats I just feel like they're trying it on.

